# btn.performClick() is not helping in triggerring button automatically

Tags: java, android

I want to trigger a button as soon as an OTP arrives and gets set in a edittext area field. OTP gets successfully set but submit button is not getting triggered itself. Where i am going wrong? Here is my code.

OTP.java

```
package com.nrb.app.nrb.otp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nrb.app.nrb.HomeScreen;
import com.nrb.app.nrb.QRresponse.MyDBHelper;
import com.nrb.app.nrb.QRresponse.ServiceCalls;
import com.nrb.app.nrb.QRscanapi.RM;
import com.nrb.app.nrb.R;
import com.nrb.app.nrb.intera.AsyncResponseActivity;
import com.nrb.app.nrb.intera.ConnectionDetectorActivity;
 import com.nrb.app.nrb.login.RegisterValidation;
import com.nrb.app.nrb.login.SignInActivity;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

   import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;


public class OTP extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Hashtable<String, String> verifiedResponseKeyValue = new Hashtable<String, String>();
private Hashtable<String, String> verifiedNestedResponseKeyValue = new Hashtable<String, String>();
private String userMobValue;
private String otpVerUrl;
private String userNameValue;
private String userEmailValue;
private String userCountryValue;
private String userId;
private MyDBHelper myDBHelper;
private String userCountryCode;
private boolean timeOut;
static EditText OtpNumber;
private ConnectionDetectorActivity cd;
private String user_exist;
private Button OTP;
Context cntx;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    cntx=this;
    OtpNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOTPVerifaction);
    cd = new ConnectionDetectorActivity(OTP.this);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    userId=bundle.getString("id");
    userEmailValue = bundle.getString("userEmailValue");
    userMobValue = bundle.getString("userMobValue");
    userNameValue = bundle.getString("userNameValue");
    userCountryValue = bundle.getString("userCountryValue");
    userCountryCode = bundle.getString("userCountryCode");
    user_exist = bundle.getString("user_exist");
    registerViews();
}

public void registerViews() {
    OtpNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOTPVerifaction);
    // TextWatcher would let us check validation error on the fly
    OtpNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            RegisterValidation.isName(OtpNumber, false);
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    });

  /*  OtpNumber.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                OTP.performClick();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });*/
}

private boolean checkValidation() {
    boolean ret = true;
    if (!RegisterValidation.isName(OtpNumber, true))
    ret = false;
    return ret;
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
private void popUpDialog(String result1, final boolean newuser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(OTP.this);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = OTP.this.getLayoutInflater();

    View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.otp_verification_dialog, null);

    TextView tv = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.otpAlertMessage1);
    tv.setText(result1);

    builder.setView(content);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    content.findViewById(R.id.btnOTPAlertOK).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                    if (newuser) {
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("defaultFrag", "newUserFrag");
                        Intent i = new Intent(OTP.this, HomeScreen.class);
                        i.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(i);
                        setResult(10);
                        finish();

                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(cntx, "Please enter Valid OTP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        OtpNumber.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
private void popUpDialogSuccess(Spannable result1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(OTP.this);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = OTP.this.getLayoutInflater();

    View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.otp_verification_dialog, null);

    TextView tv = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.otpAlertMessage1);
    tv.setText(result1);

    builder.setView(content);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    content.findViewById(R.id.btnOTPAlertOK).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                    insertUserPfref();
                }

            });
}

public void verifyOTPKEY(View v) {
    if (checkValidation()){

        EditText etOTPVerification = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOTPVerifaction);
        RM.OTP_VER_VALUE = etOTPVerification.getText().toString();
        RM.OTP_MOB_VALUE = userMobValue;

        if (user_exist.compareTo("true") == 0)
            RM.OTP_USER_EXIST_VALUE = "true";
        else
            RM.OTP_USER_EXIST_VALUE = "false";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {

            jsonObject.put(RM.OTP_VER_KEY, RM.OTP_VER_VALUE);
            jsonObject.put(RM.OTP_MOB_KEY, RM.OTP_MOB_VALUE);
            jsonObject.put(RM.OTP_USER_EXIST_KEY, RM.OTP_USER_EXIST_VALUE);
            jsonObject.put(RM.USER_Id_KEY,userId);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("==", "========= FAIL TO CREATE JSON ==========");
        }

        ServiceCalls Login = new ServiceCalls(this, RM.OTP_HOST,
                jsonObject.toString(), "Verifying", 0, new AsyncResponseActivity() {

            @Override
            public void myAsyncResponse(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("==", "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv");
                Log.d("====>>>>", result);
                parseOTPRsponseJason(result);
                Log.d("==", "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv");
            }
        });
        if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            Login.execute(1);

        } else {
            showNetworFailDialog(RM.NO_INTERNET_MSG);
        }
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter OTP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

   @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

class MyOTPAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(OTP.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(otpVerUrl);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            timeOut = true;
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        // popUpDialog(result);
        if (!timeOut)
            parseOTPRsponseJason(result);
        else
            showNetworFailDialog(RM.REQ_TIMEOUT_MSG);
        Log.d("----->", "      Response     " + result);
    }

}

private void parseOTPRsponseJason(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JSONObject json;
    JSONObject nestedJson;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(result);
        Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String key = iter.next();
            Object value = json.get(key);

            if (user_exist.compareTo("true") == 0) {
                if (key.compareTo("responseHash") == 0) {
                    nestedJson = new JSONObject(json.get(key).toString());
                    Iterator<String> nestedIter = nestedJson.keys();
                    while (nestedIter.hasNext()) {
                        String nestedKey = nestedIter.next();
                        Object nestedValue = nestedJson.get(nestedKey);
                        verifiedNestedResponseKeyValue.put(nestedKey,
                                nestedValue.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            verifiedResponseKeyValue.put(key, value.toString());

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Set<String> hKeys2 = verifiedResponseKeyValue.keySet();
        for (String string : hKeys2) {
            Log.d("====>",
                    string + " ==>" + verifiedResponseKeyValue.get(string));
        }

        String x = verifiedResponseKeyValue.get("success");

        if (x.compareTo("true") == 0) {

            if (user_exist.compareTo("true") == 0) {
                userNameValue = verifiedNestedResponseKeyValue.get("name");
                Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("HI "
                        + userNameValue + " , Welcome back to Onspot");
                wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 3,
                        3 + userNameValue.length(),
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                popUpDialogSuccess(wordtoSpan);
            } else {
                Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(
                        "Congratulations! " + userNameValue
                        + " , you are successfully registered.");
                wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 17,
                        17 + userNameValue.length(),
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                popUpDialogSuccess(wordtoSpan);
            }
        } else
            popUpDialog(
                    verifiedResponseKeyValue.get("responseMessage"), false);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("====>", "Exception");
        popUpDialog(RM.CrashError, false);
    }

}

private void insertUserPfref() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    myDBHelper = new MyDBHelper(OTP.this);
    myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    if (user_exist.compareTo("true") == 0) {

        try {
            myDBHelper.insertRegisteredUser(
                    verifiedNestedResponseKeyValue.get("email"), //
                    verifiedNestedResponseKeyValue.get("mobile_number"),//
                    verifiedNestedResponseKeyValue.get("name"), //
                    verifiedNestedResponseKeyValue.get("country"),
                    //
                    verifiedNestedResponseKeyValue.get("country_code"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("====>", "Exception");
            popUpDialog(RM.CrashError, false);
        }

        Log.d("------>", "Existing USER");
        Log.d("------>", "Existing USER" + user_exist);

    } else {
        myDBHelper.insertRegisteredUser(userEmailValue,//
                userMobValue,//
                userNameValue, //
                userCountryValue,//
                userCountryCode);
        Log.d("------>", "New User");
        Log.d("------>", "New User" + user_exist);
    }

    Log.d("------>", user_exist);
    startActivity(new Intent(OTP.this, HomeScreen.class));
    setResult(10);
    finish();
}



@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
private void showNetworFailDialog(String msg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(OTP.this);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = OTP.this.getLayoutInflater();
    View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.network_failure_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(content);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    TextView tvMsg = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.networkFailMsg);
    tvMsg.setText(msg);
    content.findViewById(R.id.btnNetworkFailureOK).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                    setResult(10);
                    finish();
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(OTP.this, SignInActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    setResult(10);
    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

public void recivedSms(String message)
{
    try
    {
        int pos=message.indexOf(':');
        String msg = message.substring(pos + 2);
        OtpNumber.setText(msg);
        OTP = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOTPVerify);
        OTP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something in response to button click
            }
        });
        OTP.performClick();
        OTP.setPressed(true);
  /*      if(OtpNumber!=null) {
            if (checkValidation()) {

                EditText etOTPVerification = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOTPVerifaction);
                RM.OTP_VER_VALUE = etOTPVerification.getText().toString();
                RM.OTP_MOB_VALUE = userMobValue;

                if (user_exist.compareTo("true") == 0)
                    RM.OTP_USER_EXIST_VALUE = "true";
                else
                    RM.OTP_USER_EXIST_VALUE = "false";

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {

                    jsonObject.put(RM.OTP_VER_KEY, RM.OTP_VER_VALUE);
                    jsonObject.put(RM.OTP_MOB_KEY, RM.OTP_MOB_VALUE);
                    jsonObject.put(RM.OTP_USER_EXIST_KEY, RM.OTP_USER_EXIST_VALUE);
                    jsonObject.put(RM.USER_Id_KEY, userId);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("==", "========= FAIL TO CREATE JSON ==========");
                }

                ServiceCalls Login = new ServiceCalls(this, RM.OTP_HOST,
                        jsonObject.toString(), "Verifying", 0, new AsyncResponseActivity() {

                    @Override
                    public void myAsyncResponse(String result) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d("==", "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv");
                        Log.d("====>>>>", result);
                        parseOTPRsponseJason(result);


                        Log.d("==", "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv");
                    }
                });
                if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                    Login.execute(1);

                } else {
                    showNetworFailDialog(RM.NO_INTERNET_MSG);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter OTP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }*/
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

IncomingMsg.java

```
package com.nrb.app.nrb.otp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by Neha on 07-03-2016.
 */
public class IncomingMsg extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null)
            {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++)
                {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String senderNum = phoneNumber ;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    try
                    {
                        if (senderNum.equals("DZ-Onspot"))
                        {
                            OTP Sms = new OTP();
                            Sms.recivedSms(message );
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){}
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

}

activity_otp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="25dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#fff"
android:padding="10dp" >

     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/onspot" />

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etOTPVerifaction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"

    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Verification Key"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:singleLine="true">

</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:onClick="verifyOTPKEY">

    <com.andexert.library.RippleView
        android:id="@+id/ripple1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:rv_rippleDuration="200"
        app:rv_type="rectangle" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOTPVerify"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shadow"
            android:text="SUBMIT"
             android:onClick="verifyOTPKEY"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
    </LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:onClick="verifyOTP"
    android:text="Enter Verification key For Login"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Comment: Your Class name and Button name are same (OTP) change that

Comment: You have created method recivedSms but from where is it getting called in your calss. Also your on click have no operation written to perform.

Comment: It is getting called from IncomingMsg.java class

Comment: You cannot instantiate an `Activity` with `new` and have it work as you're expecting, or at all, really.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting it to do nothing. You should comment out these line

```
 OTP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         // Do something in response to button click
     }
 });
```

Comment: In XML file i have set onclick to verifyOTP method

Comment: OTP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
   verifyOTPKey(v); 
     }
 });  Even this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `performClick` inside `Runnable` like this,

```
OTP.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 OTP.performClick();
            }
      });
```

**OR**

*Use view tree observer which is used to register listeners that can be notified of global changes in the view tree like here which is efficient in higher level of api than 16*

```
ViewTreeObserver vt = OTP.getViewTreeObserver();
vt.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        vt.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        OTP.performClick();
    }
});
```

Comment: and what about above one, I suggest you to move all the codes of verifyOTPKEY inside onClick of OTP.

Comment: @Neha I think performclick won't be effective in asynctask so what you can try as alternate and final option is replace the AsyncTask with Thread classes. move All the code in the doInBackground() inside the thread's run() function.